# How to convert dictionary multilevel to xml?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I want to convert dictionary have multilevel to xml, here is my code:

```
public static XElement convertDictToXml(Dictionary<string, dynamic> inputDict, string elName)
    {
        XElement el = new XElement(elName);
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, dynamic> entry in inputDict)
        {
            el.Add(new XElement(entry.Key, entry.Value));
        }
        return el;
    }
```

But I can only convert to parent level, so how can we convert from parent to all child dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

**Try on below code. I think it is what you need**

```
Dictionary<string, dynamic> inputDict = new Dictionary<string, dynamic>();
var xmlString = SerializeObject(inputDict);

public static string SerializeObject<T>(this T toSerialize)
{
    XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

    StringWriter textWriter = new StringWriter();

    xmlSerializer.Serialize(textWriter, toSerialize);
    return textWriter.ToString();
}
```